# python flask sqlalchemy - working with sqlite database from python terminal

Tags: python, flask, terminal, sqlalchemy

I have a python script app.py using Flask and SQLAlchemy to make a web application.

I have a table in the app.py script

```
class NutritionConsumed(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'nutritionconsumed'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False )
    item = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
```

in the same folder I have my sqlite database 'test.db'. Running in browser everything works fine and I can read and display data from my tables.

However, how do I access this database in the Python shell terminal?

When starting python in the same directory as my web app is located, if I run

```
>>> nutritionconsumed.query.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'nutritionconsumed' is not defined
```

but in my test.db I do have a nutritionconsumed table.

Comment: This is not about databases. This is basic Python: if you want to access a class, you need to import it - and use the name you defined, ie `NutritionConsumed` not `nutritionconsumed`

Comment: The error says it all. `nutritionconsumed is not defined` means that the variable `nutritionconsumed` does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nutritionconsumed` is name of the table and such variable does not exist by default.
If you want to query this model, you have to import its class and use the class name instead.

`NutritionConsumed.query.all()`

Answer (score 0):

The class representation of a table, in Flask, is called **Model**. User's model needs to be imported in order to be used, as every other class in Python:

```
from app import NutritionConsumed
NutritionConsumed.query.all()
```